# How to use update hibernate query using setMaxResults?

Tags: java, hibernate

I hope it is the appropriate section, I have a problem with this code

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction(); 
Query query = session.createQuery("update database set floop= :ctrl1" +" where ctrl= :ctrl2 ").setMaxResults(2); 
query.setMaxResults(2);
query.setParameter("ctrl1",3);
query.setParameter("ctrl2", 5);
```

I ask through `setMaxResults(2)` to do the update only on the first two and he makes the update of all records as I do what is wrong?? thanks for any help

I thought to use `session.createSQLQuery`, but I do not know how to do.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is posting delay but it can be helpful for others user who is looking update number of rows in DB with limit using HQL

> Unfortunatly setMaxResults() do not work update and delete hibernate
>   query. It works only select criteria.

As per HQL there is no specific solution is available and you want to update rows with number of limit then follow below steps

1. Write a HQL to select all rows with condition or range with
   setMaxResults. It will return you a List object with limit.
2. Then update the specific property (Property you want to update) and
   store Objects of these rows again by session.update() method.

I'm assuming tablename with map **Database** class and there are two variable **ctrl** and **floop** with getter and setter(***as per your question***)

```
            List<Database> list = new ArrayList<>();
            Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction(); 

            //Fetching record with limit 2 using setMaxResults()
            int setlimit = 2;
            String hql_query = "from Database where ctrl = :ctrl2";
            Query select_query = session.createQuery(hql_query).setMaxResults(setlimit);
            select_query.setParameter("ctrl2", 5);
            list = select_query.list();

            //iterating list and setting new value to particuler column or property
            int result;
            if (list != null) {
                for (Database element : list) {
                    element.setFloop(ctrl1);
                    //Here is updating data in database
                    session.update(element);
                }
                result = list.size();
            } else {
                result = 0;
            }
            System.out.println("Rows affected: " + result);

            transaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

`setMaxResults` limits the number of results which are returned by the query, not the number of affected rows.

When you only want to update a limited set of rows, you should specify these rows within the where condition. Setting a hard limit on the number of updated rows wouldn't make much sense, because there would be no way to tell which rows would be updated.

Answer (score 1):

`query.setMaxResults(2);` will be used for `selection` queries and will be ignored for `insertion/updation`. If you use it for `selection` queries, then you will get 2 records in result.

Answer (score 0):

`setMaxResults` only applies to `select`. For your problem I would perform a `select` query and then use the `query.setMaxResults(2)`, this will return a list of max 2 elements. Then loop the list returned and use session.update for the one or two elements returned.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a number of perfectly valid use-cases where you want to update only a limited number of rows and as other have already answered, the Hibernate Query cannot deal with this so you need to resort to native SQL.

You don't specify in the question which type of database you are using so **this answer will only apply to MySql**:

```
Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction(); 
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("UPDATE database SET floop= :ctrl1 WHERE ctrl= :ctrl2 LIMIT :max"); 
query.setParameter("ctrl1",3);
query.setParameter("ctrl2", 5);
query.setParameter("max", 2);
```

Please note that the sql query above needs to use the native table and column names and not the ones in your ORM model.

Comment: You can't use `:` token is in LIMIT.....You will get error `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LIMIT near line 1`

Comment: I have successfully used : token in LIMIT in Hibernate if I use native SQL. Your error message suggests that you might have tried HQL and in that case, the LIMIT keyword is not allowed.

Comment: native sql query will work fine but it is mysql dependent query and user asked question in hibernate so recommend to hql update query. Your code also working. Thanks