# update only the number of rows given in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have a method which updates the records in database and following is my method:

```
String hqlUpdate="UPDATE VFSMSServerOut vFSMSServerOut SET vFSMSServerOut.status=:rowStatus where cast(vFSMSServerOut.createDate as date) between :fromDate and :toDate and vFSMSServerOut.status in ('U','NU'))";

int rowsCount=4

public void updateProcessingRows(String hqlUpdate, Date frmDate, Date toDate,Integer rowsCount)
            throws SecMsgException {
        Session session = null;
        try {
            session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Query updateProcessingRows = session.createQuery(hqlUpdate);
            updateProcessingRows.setString("rowStatus", "QU");
            updateProcessingRows.setDate("fromDate", frmDate);
            updateProcessingRows.setDate("toDate", toDate);
            updateProcessingRows.setMaxResults(rowsCount);
            updateProcessingRows.executeUpdate();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

but instead of updating only four rows, the query updates all the rows which falls under the date range given.

how do i set number of rows to update

Comment: You need something to identify your row like an ID

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12284814/how-to-use-update-hibernate-query-using-setmaxresults/50371115#50371115 It will help to others when get same scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setMaxResults(rowsCount)` is use for UI purpose like **Pagination**. If you want to update only four rows then you have to make the change in your **Hibernate Query**.

**Edit:** As per HQL there is no specific solution is available but if you want to do this then follow these steps-

1:Write a HQL to select all rows between that date range. It will return you a **List** object .

2: Now update the *specific property* (Property you want to update) of first 'n' elements of List and store Objects of these rows again by `session.update()` method.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: would you please give me some same

Comment: No, not first four rows, the count will be given. I have to update the rows according to that count.

Comment: Count?? like upper and lower limit both or only upper limit?

Comment: No Deepak, it is not like upper and lower limit. The data will be fetched between the date range with number of rows to fetch and the same rows will be updated.

Comment: means scenario is like this.. you want to fetch 'n' rows according to date --> then want to update those 'n'. Am I getting right?